# Filter only for selected enpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to add filter for my endpoint: '/secure'.

My endpoint '/secure' is working, but rest of application throws 404, error in console:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: ModelAndView [ModelAndView: materialized View is [null]; model is {modelAndView=ModelAndView: materialized View is [null]; model is null, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.modelAndView=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, targeting=null, environment=Environment{id=1, key=localhost:8080, host=localhost:8080, name=localhost:8080, path=/1, defaultDim=true}, defaultTargeting=null, pagedefinition=null, ROLE_EDITOR=null, forms=pl.google.contentservice.front.form.model.ClmForm@706ea1f}] neither contains a view name nor a View object in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

---

Code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http = http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/assets").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority(ADMIN, USER)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and();
http.antMatcher("/secure").addFilterBefore(new Filter(tokenService),               org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: halo are you there

Answer (score 0):

Have You try add second config for '/secure'?
Now I think, You create config for '/secure' endpoint and override every else.
Check console log when app starting. You will find something like

> DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/secure'] with [ ((security chain)) ]

and nothing about '/' (every) endpoint. Check this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class SecondConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/second").addFilterAfter(new SpecializedFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when You start app You will see something different. You will see two 'DefaultSecurityFilterChain' log infos, like:

> DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/second'] with [ (default filter chain with SpecializedFilter) ]

> DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [ (default filter chain) ]

And I think it's clue for Your problem. You have specialized filter for '/second' endpoint. Be sure, Your config for '/second' endpoint (in example) is ordered less than global endpoint config (or any other matching as parent of Yours). If global endpoint config will be first, ant matcher ("/**") will matches to endpoint ("/secure") and Your filter will not be executed.
And second important thing, some of "global" config may not be applied to second filter configuration (defaults).